# Can I make a JSON-stringified object have a field whose value is a double in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am POSTing JSON from my Javascript application to this API that behaves differently if you send it doubles vs. ints. I just use `JSON.stringify` to build my request bodies. I always want to send doubles. But when I have Javascript numbers that are integral, `JSON.stringify` does this:

```
> JSON.stringify({x: 1.0});
'{"x":1}'
```

That unadorned 1 goes to the API where the other server thinks it's an int, and I get the integer behavior, which I don't want. Is there any known hack to get a double in my JSON in Javascript?

Comment: The only numeric type in JSON is decimal floating point. Your value `1.0` is exactly equivalent to `1`. The problem is not with `JSON.stringify()` but with your server API that interprets JSON incorrectly.

Comment: Fascinating! So Elasticsearch (see second sentence of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) is just broken software made by fools. I always suspected as much. Anyhow, I'm stuck with it, so hopefully I can find some hack to do this in Javascript anyway.

Comment: That's not really accurate. The value `1.0` without any other context to indicate precision (which is not something JSON can do inherently) is **exactly the same** as the value `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON (and JavaScript in general) don't distinguish between different numeric types; there's only "number". As such this is a bit outside the scope of `JSON.stringify`.

Here's a pretty awful workaround:

```
JSON.stringify({x: 1.0}).replace(
    /("(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*")|[\[:,]\s*-?\d+(?![\d.eE])/g,
    function (m0, m1) { return m1 || m0 + '.0'; }
)
```

This (rather big hammer) uses a regex to add `.0` to all numbers that don't already have a `.` and are not part of a quoted string.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: build a custom version of `JSON.stringify` which will always output numbers with a decimal point.

This simply takes an example implementation from the [Mozilla JSON documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Polyfill) and modifies the line of code that handles numbers:

```
window.JSON.stringifyDecimal = (function(){
  var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
  var isArray = Array.isArray || function (a) { return toString.call(a) === '[object Array]'; };
  var escMap = {'"': '\\"', '\\': '\\\\', '\b': '\\b', '\f': '\\f', '\n': '\\n', '\r': '\\r', '\t': '\\t'};
  var escFunc = function (m) { return escMap[m] || '\\u' + (m.charCodeAt(0) + 0x10000).toString(16).substr(1); };
  var escRE = /[\\"\u0000-\u001F\u2028\u2029]/g;
  return function stringify(value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return 'null';
    } else if (typeof value === 'number') {

      // Ensure decimal point is present
      return isFinite(value) ? value.toString() + ( Number.isInteger( value ) ? '.0' : '' ) : 'null';

    } else if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
      return value.toString();
    } else if (typeof value === 'object') {
      if (typeof value.toJSON === 'function') {
        return stringify(value.toJSON());
      } else if (isArray(value)) {
        var res = '[';
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
          res += (i ? ', ' : '') + stringify(value[i]);
        return res + ']';
      } else if (toString.call(value) === '[object Object]') {
        var tmp = [];
        for (var k in value) {
          if (value.hasOwnProperty(k))
            tmp.push(stringify(k) + ': ' + stringify(value[k]));
        }
        return '{' + tmp.join(', ') + '}';
      }
    }
    return '"' + value.toString().replace(escRE, escFunc) + '"';
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

With JSON, you have two parties: The writer and the reader. In your case, the writer is your request and you're using `JSON.stringify` to generate the JSON string, and the reader is the API (which I don't know what it uses to parse the string back to a JSON object). You need both sides to be able to understand that `1.0` should stay as is because it's a double not an integer.

JSON string itself is just text and keeps whatever you give it as is. It is the `JSON.stringify` that is converting `1.0` to `1`, so you can easily create your JSON string manually instead of using `JSON.stringify`:

```
var text = JSON.stringify({x: 1.0}); //JSON string will be {"x": 1}
var text = '{"x": 1.0}'; //JSON string will be exactly {"x": 1.0}
```

However, even if you do that, you need the other side (i.e. the API) to parse the value `1.0` as double, not an integer. Is that under your control? For example, the JavaScript `JSON.parse` function will parse the `1.0` as `1` exactly like `JSON.stringify` does:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"x": 1.0}');
alert(obj.x); //It prints 1, even though we gave it 1.0
```

Comment: @Pointy I have no idea. Thank you for reverting it back. There should be a restriction so one cannot vote down without leaving a comment. The goal of this site is so we all learn, and we learn nothing by voting down without knowing why.